# How to deal with a variable which have mixed values types in?

Tags: r

I have few columns which have both letters and numbers in.
My concern is how to treat them, is worth to use them or rather to drop them?
Further, if they  would contains useful information, how should I deal with them?
The respective variables  are : x.14, x.2, x.10. 
Data frame is:

```
 $ X   : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...

 $ x.0 : chr  "b" "a" "a" "b" ...

 $ x.1 : chr  "30,83" "58,67" "24,5" "27,83" ...

 $ x.2 : chr  "f" "4.46" "0.5" "1.54" ...

 $ x.3 : chr  "u" "u" "u" "u" ...

 $ x.4 : chr  "g" "g" "g" "g" ...

 $ x.5 : chr  "w" "q" "q" "w" ...

 $ x.6 : chr  "v" "h" "h" "v" ...

 $ x.7 : chr  "1.25" "3.04" "1.5" "3.75" ..

 $ x.8 : chr  "t" "t" "t" "t" ...

 $ x.9 : chr  "t" "t" "f" "t" ...

 $ x.10: chr  "t" "6" "f" "5" ...

 $ x.11: chr  "f" "f" "f" "t" ...

 $ x.12: chr  "g" "g" "g" "g" ...

 $ x.13: chr  "202.0" "43.0" "280.0" "100.0" ...

 $ x.14: chr  "f" "560" "824" "3" ...

 $ x.20: chr  "t" "t" "t" "t" ...

 $ x.17: chr  "116,94256980957068" "225,60625307204938" "92,08407670672422" "104,16291777029285" ...

 $ x.18: chr  "0,5787085579422866" "25,409645364400404" "2,3173371593153314" "8,04533772976642" ...

 $ x.19: chr  "202000.0" "43000.0" "280000.0" "100000.0" ...

 $ x.16: chr  "f" "f" "f" "f" ...

 $ y   : chr  "good" "good" "good" "good" ...`
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. To better answer your question,it would be interesting to know more about your objective. What do you want to achieve? You can always split the variable into multiple columns ..

Comment: It depends on how you want to use them

Comment: The objective is to make good predictions of the target y variable, a clasification problem on y variable.

Comment: You forgot to add the code

Comment: -2 vote is not a good way to welcome new contributor to the site, everyone has their first time!

Comment: Sorry for the silly question! Not everybody can ask smart questions when is beginner.  I did not ask for solution code,  I asked for a guidance, a way of work to proceed further.

Comment: If you think the numbers are the only useful things for your prediction of `y`, then you can drop the letter for sure...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like different columns were converted in different way and they need some reconverting.

A few columns (x.9, x.11) suggest, that 't' and 'f' are acronyms of TRUE and FALSE. They can be converted into 1 and 0 or left as it is.

'f' in x.14, x.2 seems to be NA or 0 converted in strange way. If so, you can change 'f' into NA (or 0) and convert the columns into numeric. Otherwise they should be treated as factors, what is not a good idea if the numbers do not repeat.

x.1, x.17, x.18 seem to be numbers with comma as a decimal point. It would be good to change ',' into '.', and convert them into numeric.

It is not so obvious in the case of x.10, where exist numbers, 'f' and 't', however, integer nature of the numbers may suggest that 'f' and 't' are 0 and 1 respectively, especially if those numbers do not exist in the column. Otherwise, it might be safer to convert 'f' and 't' into NA.